# Change Sequence of layer names - documentclass{jura}

Tags: pdftex

For my essay I use the documentclass [jura](https://ctan.org/pkg/jura?lang=de). I know that this class is pretty old but i need it to create a specific bibliography, that is used in german law. Everything works fine i just want to change a small detail:

[image]

I want to change the sequence of layer names from

A I 1. a) aa) α) αα) (1)

to

A I 1. a) aa) (1) α) αα)

In section 3.4.5. on page 11 of the document class [description](https://ctan.org/pkg/jura) it is explained how this can be done (sadly its written in german). Unfortunately I do not understand how to implement the described procedure, it just doesnt work. Maybe one of you can come up with a solution

```
\documentclass{jura}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=7cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.2cm,bottom=2.2cm,includeheadfoot,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[12pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{parskip}

\shorthandoff{"}
\parindent 0pt

\tolerance=1000
\emergencystretch=10pt

%% Formatierung von Fußnoten:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
   \setlength{\hangindent}{2em}
   \noindent
   \hb@xt@\hangindent{%
      \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\hspace{.2em}}#1}
\makeatother

\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot[\pagemark]{ \pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\renewcommand*{\frontmatter}{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{Roman}%
   \hsize\frontwidth\columnwidth\hsize\linewidth\hsize\textwidth\hsize}
\renewcommand*{\mainmatter}{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}}

\renewcommand*{\lvlastyle}{\fontsize{14}{0} \selectfont \bfseries}
\onehalfspacing
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
   \@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{}
\mainmatter
\boldmath
\restoregeometry


\begin{document}

\toc{\normalsize Mein erster Gliederungspunkt}

\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the order defined in ```jura``` incorrect?  Will other users of ```jura``` want to make the same change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the `jura` manual is part of the source code listing. In order to use this code in your own document you need to do two things.

First, instead of `\newcommand`, you need to use `\renewcommand`, because the command is already defined in the source code so using `\newcommand` results in an error.

Second, because the code contains the `@` symbol, you need to surround the definition with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Commands using this symbol are normally only found in the source code of packages and classes, and you have to mark it explicitly if you want to use this symbol in the code of your document.

Then you can modify the order of the labels in the list. However, because `jura` has some parentheses hardcoded for certain positions, you need to remove the closing parenthesis from the arabic number if you want to use it in fifth position, and similarly add a parenthesis after the double greek letters in seventh position. This added parenthesis should be upright bold for consistency.

MWE (simplified from your code, but it also works for the full code):

```
\documentclass{jura}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\J@INumberRoot}[2]{%
\ifcase#1\or
\@Alph{#2}\or
\@Roman{#2}\or
\@arabic{#2}\or
\@alph{#2}\or
\@alph{#2}\@alph{#2}\or
(\@arabic{#2}\or
\@greek{#2}\or
\@greek{#2}\@greek{#2}\textup{\textbf{)}}\or
(\@alph{#2})\or
(\@alph{#2}\@alph{#2})\or
(\@greek{#2})\or
(\@greek{#2}\@greek{#2})\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\toc{\normalsize Mein erster Gliederungspunkt}

\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}
\sub{Test}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the (1) label is now bold, instead of italic as in the original list. This can also be changed if needed, but that would take a bit more effort of modifying the original code.